# How can we improve the OO design between two interfaces

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, class-design, ooad

In the below sample code, how can we get rid of if-else ladder of concrete classes viz. `NoProcesssorFoundError` & `UnknownError`. I could extract an interface between `Event1` and `Event2` and pass their processors to process functions as the `process1` and `process2` is almost same except inputs and its procs. However, how to get rid of the if-else ladder of error concrete classe

```
public class EventProcessor {

    public void onEvent1(Event1 event1) {
        val result = process1(event1);
        if(result instanceof NoProcesssorFoundError) {
            event1.setStatus(RETRYABLE);
            ...
        } else(result instanceof UnknownError) {
            event1.setStatus(FAILED);
            ...
        }
    }

    public void onEvent2(Event2 event2) {
        val result = process2(event2);
        if(result instanceof NoProcesssorFoundError) {
            event2.setStatus(REJECTED);
            ...
        } else(result instanceof UnknownError) {
            event2.setStatus(FAILED);
            ...
        }
    }

    private Error process1(Event1 event1) {
        Event1processors.process(event1)
        ....
        if(true) {
            return new NoProcessorFoundError();
        } else {
            return new UnknownError();
        }
    }

    private Error process2(Event2 event2) {
        Event2processors.process(event2)
        ....
        if(true) {
            return new NoProcessorFoundError();
        } else {
            return new UnknownError();
        }
    }

    abstract class Error {
        class NoProcessorFoundError extends Error {}
        class UnknownError extends Error {}
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Those `Error` classes could honestly be runtime exceptions, which would allow you to use `try/catch` logic for them. If you find yourself designing something like `onEvent1`, `onEvent2`, ... it may be better to actually have an `interface EventHandler<T extends Event>` with a `onEvent(T event);` that can be overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion one good solution is the command pattern. You can check the next URL: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command/java/example.

The code should be something like:

You have to create one abstract class to define the command functions.

**Command.java**

```
public abstract class Command {
   public Command(){}

   public Error execute(){
      return null;
   }

   public Error getError(){
       if(true) {
           return new NoProcessorFoundError();
       } else {
           return new UnknownError();
       }
   }
}
```

Then, you must to create the 2 processes to split the functionalities.

**Process1.java**

```
public class Process1 extends Command {
    private Eventinterface event;

    public Process1(Eventinterface event){
       this.event = event;
    }

    @Override
    public Error execute(){
        Event1processors.process(this.event);
        Error result = getError();
        if(result instanceof NoProcesssorFoundError) {
            event1.setStatus(RETRYABLE);
            ...
        } else(result instanceof UnknownError) {
            event1.setStatus(FAILED);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Process2.java**

```
public class Process2 extends Command {
    private Eventinterface event;

    public Process2(Eventinterface event){
       this.event = event;
    }

    @Override
    public Error execute(){
        Event2processors.process(this.event);
        Error result = getError();
        if(result instanceof NoProcesssorFoundError) {
            event2.setStatus(REJECTED);
            ...
        } else(result instanceof UnknownError) {
            event2.setStatus(FAILED);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to use this patter you have 2 options. The first option is use the Processes  classes directly.

**Main1.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Event1 event1 = new Event1();
    Command process1 = new Process1(event1);
    process1.execute();
        
    Event2 event2 = new Event2();
    Command process2 = new Process2(event2);
    process2.execute();
}
```

Or you can create one CommandExecutor and get the command process using one enumerator. For this case, I think it is not the best option because if you have a lot of processes you have to define too much events before to instantiate the CommandExecutor.

**CommandExecutor.java**

```
public class CommandExecutor {
    HashMap<CommandEnum, Command> commandStack = new HashMap();
    
    public CommandExecutor(EventInterface... events) {
        commandStack.put(CommandEnum.PROCESS1, new Process1(events[0]));
        commandStack.put(CommandEnum.PROCESS2, new Process2(events[1]));
    }
    
    public Command getCommand(CommandEnum commandEndum) {
        return commandStack.get(commandEndum);
    }
}
```

Finally you can use this executor like this main file.

**Main2.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Event1 event1 = new Event1();
    Event2 event2 = new Event2();
    CommandExecutor commandExecutor = new CommandExecutor(event1, event2);
        
    Command command = commandExecutor.getCommand(CommandEnum.PROCESS1);

    command.execute();
}
```

To refactor the if-else of the Error you can implement one **Visitor pattern**. You have different choices to change this if-else in this link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-instanceof-alternatives.

Comment: The Command Pattern does not allow any arguments to its `execute()` method. If you pass it an `Eventinterface` then it's not a Command insofar as the GoF Patterns are concerned.

Comment: Well, thats true. It was my mistake. I fix the code to send parameters to the command.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a bit of polymorphism and try something like this:

```
abstract class Error {
    public abstract Status status();

    class NoProcessorFoundError extends Error {
        public static NoProcessorFoundError retrayable() {
            return new NoProcessorFoundError(RETRYABLE);
        }
        public static NoProcessorFoundError redjected() {
            return new NoProcessorFoundError(REDJECTED);
        }
    
        private final Status status;
        
        private NoProcessorFoundError(Status status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
        
        @Override
        public Status status() {
            return status;
        }
    }
    
    class UnknownError extends Error {
        @Override
        public Status status() {
            return FAILED;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And this can be used like so:

```
public void onEvent1(Event1 event1) {
    val result = process1(event1);
    event1.setStatus(event1.status());
}

public void onEvent2(Event2 event2) {
    val result = process2(event2);
    event2.setStatus(event2.status());
}

private Error process1(Event1 event1) {
    Event1processors.process(event1)
    ....
    if(true) {
        return NoProcessorFoundError.retrayable();
    } else {
        return new UnknownError();
    }
}

private Error process2(Event2 event2) {
    Event2processors.process(event2)
    ....
    if(true) {
        return NoProcessorFoundError.redjected();
    } else {
        return new UnknownError();
   }
}
```

As a result `onEvent1` and `onEvent2` are very similar, they can even be extracted together in a common `onEvent`method.